# Using .first to limit django queryset results in TypeError at /path/ object of type 'Product' has no len()

Tags: django, postgresql, django-views

I have rows in a database where some fields are repeating, such as:

```
Collection name | Product ID | Product Name | Image URL
--------------------------------------------------------
Dusk            |001         | Chair        |/images/001.jpg
Dusk            |002         | Desk         |/images/001.jpg
Dusk            |003         | Table        |/images/001-t.jpg
Rome            |004         | Chair        |/images/002.jpg
Rome            |005         | Desk         |/images/002-d.jpg
Rome            |006         | Table        |/images/002-t.jpg
Noel            |007         | Chair        |/images/003.jpg
Noel            |008         | Desk         |/images/003.jpg
Noel            |009         | Stool        |/images/003.jpg
```

There can be multiple rows having the same collection name, and some other fields may be the same also, such as the image url.

What I am trying to do is to return all rows where the collection name is distinct, but only the first row of each one.

I'm tyring to do this in a django view using '.first()', but it gives an error that my model object has no length. I know records are being returned so that isn't the issue, but I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Here is the code I am using in my views.py:

```
def bedroom_view(request):
    template = loader.get_template('/myapp/test_site/main_page/templates/main_page/bedroom.html')
    products = xroduct.objects.filter(product_category='Beds').first()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(products, 9)
    try:
        prods = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        prods = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        prods = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context={'prods': prods}    
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Since you take the *first* here,  that means `products` is in fact a *single* `Product` object, not a collection of `Product`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah of course. Maybe .first is not correct to use. How can I retrieve the first row of every set of rows where one field is equal to a certain value?

Comment: do you use a PostgreSQL database? For other database backends, this is a definitely not straightforward.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes luckily I am using postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [**`.first()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) is a way to obtain the first element of a queryset (or `None` in case there is no such element), not the *first* element *per* "group".

> **Note**: the above will not work for *most* backends. At the time of writing, it only works for *PostgreSQL*, although that can of course change in the future. Please consult the documentation on `.distinct()` to see what backends are supported.

On *PostgreSQL*, you can use the [**`.distinct(*fields)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) function to obtain rows that are distinct by one or more fields.

So here you can use:

```
def bedroom_view(request):
    template = loader.get_template('/myapp/test_site/main_page/templates/main_page/bedroom.html')
    products = Product.objects.filter(
        product_category='Beds'
    ).distinct(
        'product_collection'
    )
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(products, 9)
    try:
        prods = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        prods = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        prods = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context={'prods': prods}    
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The `product_collection` might be something else (the name of the field that contains the name of the collection).

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me, not just solve my problem but get a better understanding also. A small thing perhaps but a pretty great Xmas present :)